# R regroup factor levels based on frequency

Tags: r

In order to use `tree()` I can have no more than 32 levels for a factor. My factor `mydata$auction` has more than 32 levels. How can I regroup the levels that have low frequency, say, <10?

I tried:

```
mydata$auction[count(n$freq)<10] <- "OTHER" # didn't do it right
levels(mydata$auction)[n<=10] <-"OTHER" # didn't do it right
```

Here's what the data looks like:

```
   price  sale_date ext_color mileage ZipCode RFL FLNDR auction region condition
1  25000 2004-01-06     BEIGE    3571       1   L     L    AAAI      3        RG
2  27500 2004-01-14     BEIGE    5654       6   R     N    KCAA      5      <NA>
3  26100 2004-01-14     BEIGE    5453       9   L     L    BCAA      6      <NA>
4  27000 2004-01-28     BEIGE    6400       8   L     D     DAA      5      <NA>
5  23300 2004-03-04     BEIGE   12445       9   L     L    SCAA      6        RG
6  28000 2004-03-11     BEIGE    3019       9   L     L    SCAA      6        AV
7  27300 2004-03-16     BEIGE    4377       1   L     L    AAAI      3        RG
8  25900 2004-03-16     BEIGE    6727       1   L     L    AAAI      3        RG
9  28200 2004-03-18     BEIGE    9962       4   L     L    GDTA      4        AV
10 26300 2004-03-18     BEIGE   13012       9   L     L    SCAA      6        AV
11 26400 2004-03-25     BEIGE   20473       4   L     L    GDTA      4        AV
12 26400 2004-03-25     BEIGE   20745       4   L     L    GDTA      4        AV
13 28000 2004-03-25     BEIGE   10995       4   L     L    GDTA      4        AV
14 28300 2004-03-31     BEIGE    8042       1   R     N     BAA      3      <NA>
15 28500 2004-04-01     BEIGE    5938       8   F     F     DAA      5      <NA>
16 26200 2004-04-07     BEIGE    6704       3   R     N    OCAA      1      <NA>
17 27300 2004-04-08     BEIGE    5495       4   R     N    CINA      4      <NA>
18 27700 2004-04-08     BEIGE    1301       9   R     N    SCAA      6      <NA>
19 28700 2004-04-08     BEIGE    5659       6   R     N    GCAA      4      <NA>
20 28000 2004-04-08     BEIGE   13032       6   L     L    SLAA      5        AV
21 26000 2004-04-08     BEIGE   23990       4   F     F    SAAA      5        AV
22 28300 2004-04-08     BEIGE   11025       4   F     F     BAA      3      <NA>
23 27700 2004-04-13     BEIGE   13129       6   L     L    SLAA      5        AV
24 27100 2004-04-13     BEIGE    8559       2   L     L    BWAE      3        CL
25 27500 2004-04-13     BEIGE   11647       6   L     L    SLAA      5        AV
26 26000 2004-04-13     BEIGE    2082       2   L     L    SVAA      2      <NA>
27 27400 2004-04-13     BEIGE   11977       6   L     L    SLAA      5        AV
28 26500 2004-04-13     BEIGE   18756       4   L     L    DETA      4        AV
29 27000 2004-04-13     BEIGE   10048       4   F     F    NSAA      4      <NA>
30 27200 2004-04-13     BEIGE   10490       4   F     F    NSAA      4      <NA>
```

Comment: Hi, did you try this `levels(mydata$auction)[which(table(mydata$auction)<11)] <- "other"` ?

Comment: Aaaah I was so close. I'm getting used to the syntax but not quite there yet. thank you so much!